# Black screen on Facebook Share Dialog for Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, dialog, share

**Context**

I'm developing a simple 2D game for Android using fragments and the Facebook SDK for Android (v3.14.1).
Right now I'm working on a share button for Facebook, based on the official tutorial for the Share Dialog (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share).

My IDE is Android Studio 0.5.7 with Gradle.

**Problem**

When the player loses, there is a transition to the *fragGameOver* fragment containing a Facebook share button. If the user clicks on this button, a Facebook Share Dialog should start and he/she would be able to share a link. However, clicking on this button results on a **quick black screen** and then the app returns like if nothing had happened.

**Things I've tried**

I've already set up a Facebook App from it's website, got my app ID, uploaded the app's debug hash, and included the app's details into the manifest and strings.xml:

```
<application
    ...
    >
    <activity ...> </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
</application>
```

For the share button onClick event, I'm using this method defined in the Activity (not the fragment):

```
public void shareOnFacebook () {
    FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder mydialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this);
    if(mydialog.canPresent()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setName(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setLink("www.google.com")
                .setFragment(fragGameOver)
                .build();

        shareDialog.present();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Conclusions and Notes**

- When I click on the share button, I get the "available" message, so
  the SDK must be correctly implemented and it's connecting with the Facebook
  App installed on the phone. I'm also using Google's URL for testing
  purposes.
- In addition, I'm not getting any errors on the LogCat so far.
- I'm not implementing a UiLifecycleHelper because I don't need a
  callback to handle the result of opening the Share Dialog

Any advice on where may be the problem?

Thanks a lot!